# ProcessBuilder For Task Creation

Tags: process-builder

Hi I have Created a Process Builder for Task creation and i want that it will pick the Specific record type rather then the default one, only way i am finding it to Hardcode the Record type ID as

Task Record Type ID = 'ID[]';

Is there any Other Possible way to create. please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Hardcoded RecordTypeId use:

[Task].RecordType.DeveloperName --> Equals --> "RecordType Name"

[image: recordtype selection]

Comment: Hi Santanu Thakyou so much for help ,, Just one question i need particular record type on creation is it ok if i set in condition?? will this record type will be created..

Comment: If it is particular recordtype you have to use `=` condition